# c++ eigen block operations in templated functions taking DenseBase

Tags: c++, eigen

This works

```
Vector2d a(1,2);
VectorXd cc(10);
cc << 1.0, 2.0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9;
VectorXd rr(10);
rr << 1.0, 2.0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9;
int R(10);
Vector2d G(Vector2d::Zero());


G.noalias() -= cc.segment(4, 2) + 
               (rr.segment(1, 2) - R*Vector2d::Ones()).cwiseQuotient(a); // OK here
```

but when rr.segment(1, 2) is passed as argument to a function, the operator- in the last line doesn't compile. The problem occurs in this code

```
template <typename DerivedA, typename DerivedB, typename DerivedC>
void testFunc(MatrixBase<DerivedA>& G, const DenseBase<DerivedB>& c, const DenseBase<DerivedC>& r)
{  
   Vector2d a(1,2);
   int R(10);
   G.noalias() -= c + (r - R*Vector2d::Ones()).cwiseQuotient(a);
};

VectorXd cc(10);
cc << 1.0, 2.0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9;
VectorXd rr(10);
rr << 1.0, 2.0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9;
Vector2d G(Vector2d::Zero());
testFunc(G, cc.segment(4, 2), rr.segment(1, 2)); // ERROR : no match for 'operator-'
```

I understand that the problem is in the fact that in testFunc(), cc.segment is seen as a general DenseBase object for which the operator- is not implemented, although it is implemented for the particular class .block().

Comment: testFunc implementation works on matrix expressions so it should take MatrixBase<> arguments ( ie. adding a Vector2d is a matrix operation ). Why are you taking DenseBase<>'s ?

Comment: because I am passing .block() as arguments

Comment: AFAIR, a block of a matrix expression is still a matrix expression, hence should match MatrixBase<>... ( ie, replacing DenseBase<> with MatrixBase<> in your code compiles fine for me )

Comment: moreover, note that using derived() as suggested is like lying: the function asks for a densebase<> and internally wants to operate on a matrix ...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I see what you mean... Using ArrayBase instead of MatrixBase (to avoid .array() everywhere doesn't compile), but indeed, using MatrixBase and .array() instead of DenseBase and .derived().array() would have been the best solution :) You should have suggested it earlier ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell Eigen to use the actual type encapsulated by the `DenseBase` class by writing `c.derived()` and `r.derived()`.

Unrelated: Instead of `R*Vector2d::Ones()` write `Vector2d::Constant(R)`, and if the entire expression is element-wise operations, you should work in the Array domain anyway:

```
template <typename DerivedA, typename DerivedB, typename DerivedC>
void testFunc(MatrixBase<DerivedA>& G, const DenseBase<DerivedB>& c, const DenseBase<DerivedC>& r)
{
   Array2d a(1,2);
   int R(10);
   G.array() -= c.derived().array() + (r.derived().array() - R)/a;
}
```

(You could leave out all `.derived()` and `.array()` if you passed `ArrayBase` instead of `MatrixBase` or `DenseBase`)

Also, the `.noalias()` is only necessary if there are matrix products involved.